# Im getting an error in my class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, serialversionuid

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

      public class MyRobot extends GraphicsProgram {
        }
 }
```

That is the code I wrote and whenever I put `extends GraphicsProgram` or `ConsoleProgram`, it tells me

```
The serializable class MyRobot does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.
```

Also, when I try to run a program with this warning, it just shows a blank program.

Anyone can help me with these problems?

Comment: Please ask one question per thread.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your class is [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
>   All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The
>   serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to
>   identify the semantics of being serializable.

Answer (score 1):

The program likely displays nothing because no components have been added and nothing has been drawn in it.  But then, unless you are using one of those tricky IDEs that creates an invisible `main()` or there is another class besides `MyRobot`, I fail to see how this code could run.

---

BTW - forgot to mention the 'quick-fix' to this in Eclipse is:

1. Double click the warning in the Problems tab, to focus the problem class.
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> for 'Quick Fix'
3. Select the first or second options that appear below.

[image: Eclipse SerrialVersionUID Quick Fix]

Comment: sorry but i didnt add the code inside cuz i dinndnt thing i was necassary.

Comment: How do you know what is relevant/necessary until the problem is solved?  Please don't use made up words like 'cuz'.  That word is 'because'.  It helps people to be able to help *you.*

Answer (score 1):

Be kind to java. You use classes that have Serializable interface. They need you to `declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`. They ask you to do it. Be so kind, `declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`. :-). <sub>And +1 for it is not a bad question for a newbie.</sub>